# Handle refused to connect error when using iframe inside react app

Tags: reactjs, iframe, react-hooks

I am trying to replace Iframe with image or text when URL in it refused to connect but I could not handle this error I don't want to solve x-frame-options error I want to handle it to show image or message  when iframe can't connect
***exm1*** ==> this URL working

```
<iframe key={random} src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/b4i7j6U7Ul8" width="100%" height="100%" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-presentation" loading='lazy'/>
```

***exm2*** ==> this not work

```
<iframe key={random} src="https://www.google.com" width="100%" height="100%" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-presentation" loading='lazy'/>
```

I want to replace Iframe tag when Url refused to connect with  image or text

Answer (score -1):

1. **const youtybe = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/b4i7j6U7Ul8"**
2. **const image =  "https://www.google.com/imgae"**

```html
 <iframe key={random} src={error ? image : youtube} width="100%"
       height="100%" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin
       allow-presentation" loading='lazy'/>
```

src={error ? image : youtube}

in src : if an error image will be appear if not youtube will be appear

Comment: How can you catch errors from an iframe?